# Dropdownlist Reset SelectedValue

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I have a DropDownList connected to an ObjectDataSource. In my page load i set the selectedvalue to a specific value depending on the case. How can I in my method selectedindexchanged "reset" the selectedvalue so you still can choose from the other options? Or should I not use selectedvalue to set the defaultvalue of the dropdownlist?

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource" DataTextField="Type" DataValueField="TypeId" 
    AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" >
            </asp:DropDownList>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int default = category.TypeId;
        DropDownList.SelectedIndex = default;

}

protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int id = int.Parse(DropDownList.SelectedValue);
    Session["id"] = id;
}
```

Comment: do you please elaborate with some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only `DataBind` your `DropDownList` and set its default value `if(!IsPostBack)`:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        int default = category.TypeId;
        DropDownList.SelectedValue = default.ToString();
    }
}
```

[`Page.IsPostBack` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

Answer (score 26):

You can use ClearSelection method for Dropdown list

```
DropDownList.ClearSelection();
```

Thanks

Deepu

Answer (score 1):

Set the SelectedValue property to an empty string:

```
DropDownList.SelectedValue = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set SelectedIndex to -1

```
DropDownList.SelectedIndex = -1;
```